# How to import external vue.js library to laravel / vue.js application?

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

Hello I'm working on a Laravel/vue.js application.
I need to export csv with vue.js.
But the problem is, I don't know how to import external library correctly.

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-chartjs');
require('vue-json-csv');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));
Vue.component('order-component', require('./components/OrderComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('product-component', require('./components/ProductComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('customer-component', require('./components/CustomerComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('ca-component', require('./components/CustomerComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('csv-component', require('./components/CsvComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('test-customer-component', require('./components/TestCustomerComponent.vue').default);
```

In my component Order :

```
<script>
    import JsonCSV from 'vue-json-csv'
    Vue.component('downloadCsv', JsonCSV)
...
```

Comment: Is `vue-json-csv` the library you're having issue with?

Comment: Yes, it's this library

Comment: Can you show how you're using the component i.e. the HTML part of it.